# Combine these two images into a six-channel graph as a sample training in yolov5

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5, dataloader

I am a sophomore who has just started deep learning and python, and I am completing the first big assignment assigned by the teacher, how to read two 3-channel pictures consecutively from the dataset and merge them into one 6-channel picture as a training sample? How to modify the dataloader?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F79oa.png)
Combining these two images into a six-channel graph as a sample training, how do I modify my code?

Comment: why would you want to combine the images? Are you maybe asking about the batch_size in pytorch? I don't see how combining two images would result in a better-performing model, Could you share your code and what you have tried so far? Maybe this would help us understand your issue better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to compare the difference between the two input images and combine two 3-channel images as training samples for the network